# Dynamically disable option of html-select in Angular 4

Tags: angular, html-select

is there a way to disable an option of a select element in angular 4?

I tried something like this but it does not work

```
<select type="number" [(ngModel)]="selectedItem">
    <option [disabled]="i.disabled" *ngFor="let i of items" [ngValue]="i.id">{{i.designator}}</option>
</select>
```

Whereabout i.disabled contains a boolean.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: [disabled]="true"

Comment: I just added [disabled]="true" but still all options are not disabled

Comment: your code is working without any changes. What is your array object looks like?

Comment: Thank you! You were right. I was doing the changes on a different component. Many thanks. it was my fault

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works fine here

```
<select type="number" [(ngModel)]="selectedItem">
    <option [disabled]="i.disabled" *ngFor="let i of items" [ngValue]="i.name">{{i.name}}</option>
</select>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/mrywHpwEgTRs313S2iLM?p=preview)**

Comment: Ok nice, but what about dynamic disabling, based on some other action, from some method triggered in component for example. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1):

```
this.items = [{id:1,disabled:true,designator:123}];

<select type="number" [(ngModel)]="selectedItem">
              <option [disabled]="i.disabled" *ngFor="let i of items" [ngValue]="i.id">{{i.designator}}</option>
          </select>
```

working fine.